# Android: alteração indevida no layout devido a animação

Tags: android, android-layout, animação

Galera, estou com uma problema aqui e já postei no stackoverflow internacional, porém ninguem me respondeu, então estou postando aqui para ver se tem alguma alma caridosa que me ajude. Vamos lá!!

Eu simplismente queria fazer uma listagem de "tarefas" então usei o seguinte layout para listar:

lauout/fragment_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/no_item_message"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

E segue aqui os itens que vão ser inseridos na lista:

layout/task.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:showDividers="middle"
 android:divider="?android:dividerVertical">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/task_checkbox"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="245dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:id="@+id/task_container">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:hint="@string/title_task"
    android:id="@+id/title_task"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/task_vinculado"
    android:id="@+id/task_vinculado"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/limit_date"
    android:id="@+id/limit_date"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/delete_task_button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_remove_item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Tudo saiu como eu queria e meu layout ficou assim:

[Layout Preview](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img823/2152/ext3.png) (as cores eu configurei no código em Java)

Então eu decidi fazer as animações de layout descritos no site do Android Developers
(exatamente como está aqui: developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html)

Então eu substitui o arquivo layout/fragment_list.xml pelo seguinte arquivo:

layout/teste.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" />

</ScrollView>

<TextView
   android:id="@android:id/empty"
   style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:text="@string/no_task"
   android:padding="32dp"
   android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />

</FrameLayout>
```

E eu vou manipulando a Lista manualmente em um fragmento desta forma:

TaskFragment.java: (o código está simplificado para melhor entendimento)

```
public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {
  private ViewGroup mContainerView;
  private View view;


  public TaskFragment() {
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teste, container, false);
    assert view != null;

    mContainerView = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.container);

    return view;
  }


  @Override
  public void onStart(){
     super.onStart();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = NectarContract.Task.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uri, NectarContract.Task.PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    assert c != null;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setId(c.getInt(NectarContract.COLUMN_TASK_ID));
        task.setTitle(c.getString(NectarContract.COLUMN_TASK_TITLE));
        task.setVinculado(c.getString(NectarContract.COLUMN_TASK_VINCULADO));
        task.setEnd(c.getString(NectarContract.COLUMN_TASK_END));
        task.setPrioridade(c.getInt(NectarContract.COLUMN_TASK_PRIORIDADE));

        view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        populate(task);
     }
  }

  private void populate(final Task task){
    final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.task, mContainerView, false);

    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) newView.findViewById(R.id.task_checkbox);
    checkbox.setTag(task.getId());
    TextView title = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.title_task);
    TextView vinculado = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.task_vinculado);
    TextView end = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.limit_date);
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) newView.findViewById(R.id.task_container);

    title.setText(task.getTitle());
    if (task.getPrioridade() == 0) {
        title.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    if (task.getPrioridade() == 1) {
        title.setTextColor(0xFFE29400);
    }
    if (task.getPrioridade() == 2) {
        title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    vinculado.setText("Vinculado a: " + task.getVinculado());
    end.setText("Data prevista: " + task.getEndString());

    container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), TaskActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ARG_TASK, task);
            intent.putExtra(TaskActivity.USER, user);
            intent.putExtra(TaskActivity.METHOD, TaskActivity.UPDATE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
    newView.findViewById(R.id.delete_task_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mContainerView.removeView(newView);
            if (mContainerView.getChildCount() == 0) {
                view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    mContainerView.addView(newView, 0);
  }
}
```

Só que utilizando uma lista dessa forma, alterou as configurações do meu layout. Olha só:

[Layout Preview 2](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img820/6783/d87c.png)

Eu já fiz de tudo para alterar isso, para voltar o visual antigo, e eu não consegui de maneira alguma. O que eu quero é continuar com esse layout que suporta animação, porém com o visual antigo.

Nota: todas as alterações que eu faço em layout/task.xml, não fica certinho como mostra no preview do Android Studio, eu tenho que ir rodando a aplicação e testando até ficar na configuração que quero, e ainda há coisas que eu não consigo mudar! Será isso um problema de API da animação?

Obrigado desde já por quem tentar me ajudar nisso!!

Comment: O problema é no checkbox, cor do texto e padding né? Sabe que "não" é recomendado ter um ListView dentro de um ScrollView. Não entendi bem a motivação para mudar do `fragment_list.xml` pelo `teste.xml`? Era só teste mesmo? Além disso, poderia tentar detalhar melhor o problema? Tem muito código e não ficou claro o problema pra mim...

Comment: Exatamente, problema no checkbox. Mas eu não estou usando o ListView dentro de ScrollView, é um LinearLayout dentro do ScrollView. Na verdade eu substitui o fragment_list.xml pelo teste.xml exatamente pq ele substitui um ListView pelo LinearLayout dentro do ScrollView, aí eu manipulo os itens dentro do LinearLayout atravez de um objeto ViewGroup lá no código do meu fragmento, com a operação de adicionar e remover ele efetua uma animação automaticamente como mostrado nesse link: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

O problema é que isso tá dando pau na checkbox.

Comment: Ah... entendi, não esta mais usando um `Adapter` para representar seu modelo no `ListView` e sim fazendo tudo isso manualmente... Pra mim não faz sentido essa mudança de "tema". Poderia incluir o código que infla o layout e preenche os dados? Além disso, já tentou usar o atributo `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` no `ListView`?

Comment: olha só o que tá comentado no código da app de exemplo do site do Android Developers: "A vertical LinearLayout in a ScrollView. This emulates a ListView (and is lighter weight
 than a ListView when there aren't many rows).
Note that this LinearLayout has the "animateLayoutChanges" property set to true.
This tells the framework to automatically animate child views (in this case, rows)
 as they are added to and removed from the LinearLayout."

Comment: Cara, desde já agradeço sua ajuda. Obrigado pela atenção bro. Eu nao **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"** no ListView pq como uso adapter, eu acabo não conseguindo manipular item por item no ListView. O que eu faço nesses casos é repopular minha ListView.

Comment: pronto, editei o post e postei o código que eu manipulo a lista manualmente dentro do LinearLayout. Olha se ficou melhor de entender?

Comment: Ok, irei olhar.

Comment: Obrigado bro. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Uma coisa que achei estranho é usar o `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` no `final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.task, mContainerView, false);
`. Teste uma coisa: Criei uma variável local para guardar o `LayoutInflater`, inicialize-o no `onCreateView` usando apenas o contexto da `Activity` (talvez, não tenho certeza, mas usando o contexto da aplicação, esteja perdendo o tema da sua `Activity`) e reutilize esse `LayoutInflater` no método `populate`. Ah, passe o container como `null` no método `inflate`.

Comment: nossa cara, muuuuuuito obrigado. Resolveu meu problema aqui. 
Eu não cheguei a inicializar o `LayoutInflater` em `onCreateView`, na verdade eu só substitui a linha `final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.task‌​, mContainerView, false);`  por `final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.task, mContainerView, false);`

Vc é o cara, valeu. Como posso te dar "pontos" aqui no forum? Eu ainda sou novo com isso aqui! hauahauahua

Comment: Vou colocar essa recomendação do `Context` que é passado no `LayoutInflater` como resposta para poder aceitar. De nada, é pra isso que estamos aqui :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere o `Context` passado para o `LayoutInflater`, passando o `Application` porque provavelmente há perda de informação em relação ao tema da `Activity`.

Poderá usar:

```
LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
// ou
getActivity().getLayoutInflater() // Sugerido nos comentários
// ou
(LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Exatamente isso! Muito obrigado Walkim!